# What am I doing wrong in: Remove all nodes with a given value Python3?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I am a fresh learner and trying to get used to python and data structures on codecademy.

I am currently learning linked list.

My homework is making a method for removing all nodes with a given data. I tried many ways but keep getting stuck when removing 2+ nodes with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_value'

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = next_node
    
  def get_value(self):
    return self.value
  
  def get_next_node(self):
    return self.next_node
  
  def set_next_node(self, next_node):
    self.next_node = next_node

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, value=None):
    self.head_node = Node(value)
  
  def get_head_node(self):
    return self.head_node
  
  def insert_beginning(self, new_value):
    new_node = Node(new_value)
    new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)
    self.head_node = new_node
    
  def stringify_list(self):
    string_list = ""
    current_node = self.get_head_node()
    while current_node:
      if current_node.get_value() != None:
        string_list += str(current_node.get_value()) + "\n"
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    return string_list

  def remove_all_node(self, value_to_remove):
    appeared_times = self.stringify_list().count(str(value_to_remove))
    for i in range(0, appeared_times):
       current_node = self.get_head_node()
       if current_node.get_value() == value_to_remove:
         self.head_node = current_node.get_next_node()
       else:
         while current_node:
           next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
           if next_node.get_value() == value_to_remove:
             current_node.set_next_node(next_node.get_next_node())
             current_node = None
           else:
             current_node = next_node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issues are:

- `self.stringify_list().count(str(value_to_remove))` is not the right way to count the occurrences. For instance, if you have a tree with just one node, which has value 22, then `.count("2")` will return 2 because it counts *substrings*, so that is not what you need.
- When `next_node` is `None`, then `if next_node.get_value() == value_to_remove` will raise an error. First check that `next_node` is not `None`.

Some other remarks:

- Your `LinkedList` constructor should not create a node instance. It should just set the `head_node` attribute to `None`, which is the most accurate way to say that this list has *no* nodes. Be aware that the user may decide to insert a `None` value in the list, and that should then be regarded as a real node. In short, don't create a node in this constructor. Then you can also drop this condition from the `stringify_list` method (which would have wrong effects when there is a real node that happens to have `None` as value):

  ```
  if current_node.get_value() != None
  ```
- The code for `insert_beginning` is correct, but you could take benefit from the fact that the `Node` constructor takes a second argument. So it could just be:

  ```
    def insert_beginning(self, new_value):
      self.head_node = Node(new_value, self.get_head_node())
  ```
- In each iteration you start from the head of the list to search for an occurrence. That is a waste of time. You should just continue the search after the spot where you removed the previous occurrence.

Here is the corrected version of `remove_all_node`:

```
  def remove_all_node(self, value_to_remove):
    current_node = self.get_head_node()
    while current_node and current_node.get_value() == value_to_remove:
      self.head_node = current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    while current_node:
      next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
      if next_node and next_node.get_value() == value_to_remove:
        current_node.set_next_node(next_node.get_next_node())
      else:
        current_node = next_node
```